# jQuery setting input.value = input.title (or other input attribute)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, this

I'm trying to figure out how to set the `input` value of a text field to the value of it's `title` when the page loads, as a way to show placeholder text. I'm using an HTML4 Strict doctype. I don't want to store the placeholder text in the input value, because I don't want people without javascript to have to delete the text before typing. I want it to be added with javascript, and then removed when the input gains focus. I have the `focus()` and `blur()` methods working, but I can't figure out how to write the initial pageload function to pass the input's title to the `val()` function.

I currently have this code:

```
// This doesn't work, it grabs the page title:
$('#item-search').val(this.title);

// Works:
$('#item-search').focus(function() {
    if (this.value == this.title) {
        this.value = '';
    } 
});

// Works: 
$('#item-search').blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = this.title;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to add another variation, `.val()` can [accept a function as its parameter](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex-%20value), fixing your `this` issues:

```
$('#item-search').val(function () {
    return this.title;
});
```

Comment: They are specific hacks to this situation and won't work as a general solution.

Comment: The other answers work, but this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the current scope. In your first example, its referring to `document`.

You may want.

```
$('#item-search').val($('#item-search').attr('title'));
```

Even better:

```
var $itemSearch = $('#item-search');
$itemSearch.val($itemSearch.attr('title'));
```

Comment: Would your second solution be a performance improvement in my case? I'm wondering if defining the $itemSearch variable and then using it for my 3 functions would be faster than making jQuery traverse the DOM 3x—or does jQuery cache the element if the same selector is called more than once?

Comment: it would be, but im not sure it would be noticeable.

Comment: @TimMackey Not a big difference with an ID selector, but it is a general best practice (with more complicated selectors it will become an issue). Also, defining selectors only once is recommended, in case you have to change it. `'#item-search'` is basically a constant.

Comment: @bažmegakapa, that makes a lot of sense—I can see how it could make a big perpormance difference with complex selectors, and defining a variable once is definitely more maintainable. When you said that "`'#item-search'` is basically a constant," do you mean because it is an ID selector (ID selectors being always and everywhere unique)?

Comment: @TimMackey It could apply to any selector. I meant that selectors do not really change, they are not "variable", but "constant", so you can basically define a constant for them (which Javascript does not have).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#item-search').val(this.title);
```

In this line `this` refer the document(`html`) and set the `<title>`. To accomplish you job do this:

```
$('#item-search').val($('#item-search').attr('title'));
```

Comment: missing single quote on the `attr('title'));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#item-search').val($('#item-search').attr('title'));
```

Comment: *fixed* thanks,
it's sometimes confusing working with jquery framework and without it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
$('#item-search').val($("#item-search").attr("title"));
```